# Python array not working

Tags: python

This is so simple! Why isnt it working?!?!?

My python program...

```
def main():
    mont = []
    mont[0] = "bnkj1"
    mont[1] = "bnkj2"
    mont[2] = "bnkj3"

    print(mont[0])

main()
```

This is what I get when running it...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hunterjamesnelson/Documents/bruceArray.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/hunterjamesnelson/Documents/bruceArray.py", line 3, in main
    mont[0] = "bnkj1",
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Like the error message indicates, in Python these are `list`s; "array", to us, means something very different and less often used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't allow you to append just by assigning to an index out of the range of the list. You need to use `.append` instead:

```
def main():
    mont = []
    mont.append("bnkj1")
    mont.append("bnkj2")
    mont.append("bnkj3")

    print(mont[0])

main()
```

Comment: Or in his case just `mont = ['bnkj1', 'bnkj2', 'bnkj3']`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you need to specify the list size when you initialize it to use it like you do. You get an error because the list you defined has length 0. So accessing on any index will be out of range.

```
def main():
    mont = [None]*3
    mont[0] = "bnkj1"
    mont[1] = "bnkj2"
    mont[2] = "bnkj3"

    print(mont[0])

main()
```

alternativ you can use `.append()` to increase the size and adding an element.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    mont = []           # <- this is a zero-length list
    mont[0] = "bnkj1"   # <- there is no mont[0] to assign to
```

Answer (score 0):

This avoids building an empty list and then appending to it thrice.

```
def main():
    mont = ["bnkj1", "bnkj2", "bnkj3"]
    print(mont[0])

main()
```